# prove function is not continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $f$ from the reals to the reals be given by $f(x)=4+x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=4-x$ if $x$ is irrational. Prove $f$ is not continuous where $R$ has standard topology .

Let $U$ be an open set. I have to prove $f^{-1}(U)$ is not necessarily open.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Do you have an intuitive idea of what continuity means? If so, then how do you "know" that this function not continuous?

Comment: Pick a specific simple non-empty open set — an open interval would be a good choice, and see what its inverse image is. With this particular function it doesn’t matter what non-empty open set you pick: its inverse image won’t be open, and you just have to figure out why.

Comment: It is enough to **find** a specific open set $U$ such that its preimage under $f$ is not open.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I can't figure out what the inverse image would be

Comment: In this particular problem $f$ is actually invertible; try to figure out what the function $f^{-1}$ is. HINT: $4\pm x$ is rational if and only if $x$ is rational.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the inverse is x-4 if x is rational and 4-x if x is irrational?

Comment: @user108605 that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need any open set $U$ whose image is not open.  For example, take $U = (1,2)$.

We find that $f^{-1}(U) = [(-3,-2) \setminus \Bbb Q] \cup [(2,3)\cap \Bbb Q]$. This set is not open.

Comment: but how do I prove the pre image is not open?

Comment: Can you find the preimage, in some kind of set notation?

Comment: it includes its smallest member -2 so its not open

Comment: Is that how you define open sets???

Comment: Thanks. how do you obtain this?

Comment: Using your definition of $f^{-1}$.